# Is it possible to include a file generated in previous stages of the Makefile?

Tags: makefile, include

Say I want to use the following Makefile:

```
config:
    echo "STR = YAY" > params

-include params

do_print: config
    echo $(STR)
```

For this to work I need to run make in two steps, first `make config` to generate the `params` file and only then I can run `make do_print` and it would print the `YAY`.
I am looking for a way that running `make do_print` will be able to generate the `params` file , include it and execute the print in "one pass".

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to name your target `params` (what it really is) instead of `config` (what it is not)? As you wrote it `make` cannot guess that the `config:` rule builds `params`.

Comment: Thanks , I changed it to `params config:` so it will be backward compatible for users to have it same as it always was and it seems to be doing the trick.

Comment: Note that if it is generated dynamically and the contents may change, you should add `.PHONY: params` to have it regenerated on every run. Otherwise `make` will be happy when the file exists, whatever is inside.

Comment: @raspy Declaring it as phony does not really work as you would expect: `params` will be remade each time but `make` will not restart and re-read it. This (undocumented) behaviour avoids infinite loops. So, if you really want to re-generate and re-read it each time, but only once, better use G.M. solution or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

The main issue with your `makefile` as shown is that you don't provide `make` with the correct information re. dependencies.  The following...

```
config:
    echo "STR = YAY" > params
```

tells `make` that running the commands will create/update the non-phony target named `config`.  But it doesn't.  It actually creates/updates a file named `params`.  Since `params` is a real file and also the one you want to include just rename the target and adjust the rest of the `makefile` accordingly.  In addition you need (I think?) to use a phony dependency to force the `params` rule to be executed every time `make` is invoked and to ensure `params` is only updated if necessary (to prevent an infinite loop).  Try something like...

```
.PHONY: FORCE

params: FORCE
    echo "STR = YAY" > $@.temp
    diff -q $@ $@.temp || cp $@.temp $@

-include params

do_print: params
    echo $(STR)
```

Comment: You really don't want to force `params`, not with `.PHONY` _or_ `FORCE`.  Your make invocation will run forever.

Comment: But the target `params` will only be updated/reread if it actually differs from the newly generated temp file `params.temp`.  So the `diff ... || cp ...` command should prevent it updating continuously, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you dont't want to use another target , then you could use below, but am not sure about your usecase:

```
$(shell echo "STR = YAY" > params)
-include params

do_print:
    echo $(STR)
```

**OR** 
As suggested by @Renaud Pacalet, you could change the name of your target